# Why when searching inside files for text when there are a lot of files to search the memory usage is raise over 2GB?

Tags: c#, winforms

I had to shut down the app from task manager.

For example I'm searching the entire D:\ drive and there are over 400000 files.
The first time it's getting the files and the second time search in each file for a specific given string.

Starting a background worker:

```
private void startButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items.Clear();
            numberoffiles = 0;
            numberofrestrictedFiles = 0;
            numberofdirs = 0;
            label24.Text = "0";
            label1.Text = "0";
            label15.Text = "0";
            Logger.Write("Operation started");
            label21.Text = "Phase 1: Retrieving files";
            label21.Visible = true;
            startButton.Enabled = false;
            stopButton.Enabled = true;
            pauseresumeButton.Enabled = true;
            label1.Select();
            timer1.Start();
            if (!backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
            {
                SetWorkerMode(true);
                backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
        }
```

Inside the DoWork:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
            _stopwatch.Restart();

            string[] values = textBox1.Text.Split(new string[] { ",," }, StringSplitOptions.None);
            DirSearch(textBox3.Text, textBox2.Text, values, worker, e);

            _stopwatch.Stop();
        }
```

The DirSearch method:

```
int numberofdirs = 0;
        void DirSearch(string rootDirectory, string filesExtension, string[] textToSearch, BackgroundWorker worker, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            List<string> resultsoftextfound = new List<string>();
            List<string> resultsoftextfound1 = new List<string>();
            List<string> filePathList = new List<string>();
            int numberoffiles = 0;
            try
            {
                filePathList = SearchAccessibleFilesNoDistinct(rootDirectory, null,worker,e).ToList();
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                string ad = err.ToString();
            }
            label21.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                    {
                        label21.Text = "Phase 2: Searching in files";
                    });

            MyProgress myp = new MyProgress();
            myp.Report4 = filePathList.Count.ToString();
            foreach (string file in filePathList)
            {
                try
                {
                    var tempFR = File.ReadAllText(file);
                    _busy.WaitOne();
                    if (worker.CancellationPending == true)
                    {
                        e.Cancel = true;
                        return;
                    }

                    bool reportedFile = false;

                    for (int i = 0; i < textToSearch.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (tempFR.IndexOf(textToSearch[i], StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0)
                        {
                            resultsoftextfound.Add(file + "  " + textToSearch[i]);
                            if (!reportedFile)
                            {
                                numberoffiles++;

                                myp.Report1 = file;
                                myp.Report2 = numberoffiles.ToString();
                                myp.Report3 = textToSearch[i];
                                backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, myp);
                                reportedFile = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    numberofdirs++;
                    label1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                    {
                        label1.Text = string.Format("{0}/{1}", numberofdirs, myp.Report4);
                        label1.Visible = true;
                    });
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                }
            }
        }
```

And the two recursive searching methods it's a bit long but all the methods are connected to each other:

```
int counter = 0;
        IEnumerable<string> SearchAccessibleFilesNoDistinctOnlyExtension(string root, List<string> files)
        {
            if (files == null)
                files = new List<string>();
            if (Directory.Exists(root))
            {
                foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(root))
                {
                    string extension = Path.GetExtension(file);
                    if (!files.Contains(extension))
                    {
                        files.Add(extension);
                        counter++;
                    }
                }

                foreach (var subDir in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(root))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        SearchAccessibleFilesNoDistinctOnlyExtension(subDir, files);
                    }
                    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
            return files;
        }

        string restrictedFile = "";
        List<string> restrictedFiles = new List<string>();
        int numberofrestrictedFiles = 0;
        int numberoffiles = 0;
        IEnumerable<string> SearchAccessibleFilesNoDistinct(string root, List<string> files,BackgroundWorker worker, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            _busy.WaitOne();
            if (files == null)
                files = new List<string>();
            if (Directory.Exists(root))
            {
                foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(root))
                {
                    if (worker.CancellationPending == true)
                    {
                        e.Cancel = true;
                        return files;
                    }
                    restrictedFile = file;
                    string ext = Path.GetExtension(file);
                    if (!files.Contains(file) && (ext == "." + textBox2.Text || textBox2.Text == "*"))
                    //if (!files.Contains(file) && ext == textBox2.Text)
                    {
                        files.Add(file);
                    }
                    numberoffiles++;
                    label24.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                    {
                        label24.Text = numberoffiles.ToString();
                        label24.Visible = true;
                    });
                }
                foreach (var subDir in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(root))
                {
                    if (worker.CancellationPending == true)
                    {
                        e.Cancel = true;
                        return files;
                    }
                    try
                    {
                        SearchAccessibleFilesNoDistinct(subDir, files,worker, e);
                        //files.Add(subDir);
                    }
                    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
                    {
                        restrictedFiles.Add(restrictedFile);
                        numberofrestrictedFiles++;
                        label11.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                        {
                            label11.Text = numberofrestrictedFiles.ToString();
                            label11.Visible = true;
                        });
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }
            return files;
        }
```

It's working fine with small amount of files to search in.
But I want to be able to search also over a large size amount of files. For example 400000 files. The problem is that at some point it's taking all the ram usage 2GB memory usage even close to 3GB at some points.

Comment: Just some suggestions: 1. Try to use IDisposable as much as possible 2. Maybe you need a GC.Collect() at some point 3. Try to await your long-running tasks to prevent the UI thread being blocked 4. This could be an area where you could use unsafe code to better manage variable in memory

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! What are the sizes of the files? Maybe you have very large files, and by doing `File.ReadAllText` you're loading the entire file.

Comment: I copied your code, filled in the few missing pieces, and ran it.  I had it search about 260000 files.  My memory usage only went up to about 100 MB.  So I think the high memory usage must either be in one of the missing code pieces or something with your input files.  The code I filled in were SetWorkerMode, MyProgress class, and backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged.  Are your input files lots of large text files?

Comment: @gunnerone My code of form1 is very long. I can send you the whole project. A bit messed. But I guess since I searched over my entire D:\ drive there are also some big file some might be over 2-3GB size and not all of them are text files. I searched in all the files types.

Comment: Does the high memory usage happen the first time you run the scan or after doing it a few times?  If you want to send me a link to the whole project I'll take a look at it.  I scanned my C:\ drive, so it was just all the random files on there.